# wxPython Buttons and Pop up Message

Tags: python-2.7, button, dialog, wxpython, panel

I'm creating a wxPython App which lists rows of buttons. When the buttons are pressed, a pop-up message (which will be a quote) is displayed. I'm having trouble programming the buttons to display a pop up message.

1) I'm having trouble having a pop up message displayed after wx.ToggleButton  is clicked.

2) The other problem is how I can make multiple buttons which will each display a different message

```
 import wx

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(350,300))
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(550,500))

    self.CreateStatusBar() #Creates the Statusbar in bottom
        filemenu = wx.Menu() 
        #About and Exit
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About",
" Information about this programme")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit",
" Terminate the programme")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        wx.ToggleButton(panel, 1, 'Quote1', (100,100))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)






    def Quote1(self, e):

        description = """Message Here"""



    def OnAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, "About here ")

        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'customdialog1.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Centre()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to create a series of buttons and bind them to the same handler. I wrote on this topic a few years ago [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/). Using that example, I created something simple using your example:

```
import wx

class TransientMessage(wx.PopupTransientWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, style, message):
        wx.PopupTransientWindow.__init__(self, parent, style)

        text = wx.StaticText(self, label=message)
        sz = text.GetBestSize()
        self.SetSize( (sz.width+20, sz.height+20))


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(550,500))

        self.CreateStatusBar() #Creates the Statusbar in bottom
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        #About and Exit
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About",
                                    " Information about this programme")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit",
                                   " Terminate the programme")

        self.quotes = {'btn1': 'quote 1',
                       'btn2': 'another quote',
                       'btn3': 'Fore Score and 7 Years Ago'}

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        topSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        for btn in self.quotes:
            new_btn = wx.Button(panel, label=btn, name=btn)
            topSizer.Add(new_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            new_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Quote1)

        panel.SetSizer(topSizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)


    def Quote1(self, e):
        btn = e.GetEventObject()
        quote = self.quotes[btn.GetName()]
        win = TransientMessage(self,
                               wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,
                               quote)

        pos = btn.ClientToScreen( (0,0) )
        sz =  btn.GetSize()
        win.Position(pos, (0, sz[1]))

        win.Popup()


    def OnAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, "About here ")

        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'customdialog1.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Centre()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

You will probably want to change it up slightly so that the value of the quote dictionary is another data structure that contains the label of the button and the quote instead of using the same string for the button's label and its name.